# Can someone give an example of the situation described here about thread-safe variables?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning about Java multi-threading and came across a [very good tutorial online](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-safety.html). But I am not sure if I understand a part where the writer explains about thread-safe objects, variables and such. To quote him,

```
public void someMethod(){

  LocalObject localObject = new LocalObject();

  localObject.callMethod();
  method2(localObject);
}

public void method2(LocalObject localObject){
  localObject.setValue("value");
}
```

> ...the whole method someMethod() is thread safe. Even if the LocalObject instance is passed as parameter to other methods in the same class, or in other classes, the use of it is thread safe. The only exception is of course, if one of the methods called with the LocalObject as parameter, stores the LocalObject instance in a way that allows access to it from other threads.

I understand why the LocalObject instance is thread-safe. But I would like to see an example of the exception case (the last line in the above block quote). If someone could write a code snippet that fits what's written in the last line, that would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SomeClass {
    private LocalObject cachedLocalObject;

    public void someMethod() {
        LocalObject localObject = new LocalObject();
        localObject.callMethod();
        method2(localObject);
    }

    public void method2(LocalObject localObject) {
        this.cachedLocalObject = localObject;
        localObject.setValue("value");
    }

    public LocalObject getCachedLocalObject() { return cachedLocalObject; }
}
```

The combination of caching the object in `method2()` and then exposing it for external use in `getCachedLocalObject()` breaks threadsafety: some other thread can use `getCachedLocalObject()` to obtain and modify `cachedLocalObject`.

Comment: thank you! I understand what the author meant by "stores LocalObject instance in a way that allows access to it from other threads" now.

Answer (score 1):

The contrast is demonstrated in the next part: "Object Members". As long as the object remains local to thread, it will be inherently thread-safe. But as soon as the reference is assigned to an object's field, any thread with a reference to the parent object can gain access to its fields, rendering them (potentially) not thread-safe.

Comment: Right... I should have kept reading until I decided to post this question xD Thanks for the answer. I'll let mods decide if this post should be deleted.